# Apply function recursively to pairs of files in a folder

Tags: r

I want to compare a single column from each of two files. The files are contained in a folder and are listed in order of comparison eg.

```
File_1a
File_1b
File_2a
File_2b
File_3a
File_3b
```

I want to perform a function that compares a single column from each of the two files and then outputs a number. It doesnt really matter what Im comparing as I assure you the code works fine. For each comparison I then want to plot the number (this also works fine)

Here is what I have so far, but Im stuck on how to go through all the files in the folder and also how to keep the output so that I can then plot it. Thanks in advance

```
df <- read.delim(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
df2 <- read.delim(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
View(df)

total <- merge(df,df2,by="Start")
total[,5][total[,5] == "2"] <- "d"
total[,9][total[,9] == "2"] <- "d"
View(total)
total[,5][total[,5] < 2 & total[,5] !="d"] <- "l"
total[,9][total[,9] < 2 & total[,9] !="d"] <- "l"
View(total)
total[,5][total[,5] > 2 & total[,5] !="l" & total[,5] !="d"] <- "g"
total[,9][total[,9] > 2 & total[,9] !="l" & total[,9] !="d"] <- "g"
View(total)
total$agree <- ifelse((total[,5] == total[,9]),"agree","disagree") 
View(total)

print(sum(total$agree == "agree")/nrow(total)*100)
print(sum(total$agree == "disagree")/nrow(total)*100)
```

An example data set which should be the same format in all the files is:

```
Chromosome Start rt med CN
          1              1   2    4     2
          1             10  1    2     3
         10             1   1    3     2
```

I want the comparison to be between pairs of consecutive files as numbered above.

Comment: Yes- Ive tried to move this to chat if that's OK with you. I checked the string and I got List of 1
 $ :'data.frame': 309579 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Chromosome : Factor w/ 24 levels "1","10","11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ Start      : int [1:309579] 1 10001 20001 30001 40001 50001 60001 70001 80001 90001 ...
  ..$ Ratio      : num [1:309579] -1 3.53 1.04 1.04 1.11 ...
  ..$ MedianRatio: num [1:309579] -1 3.53 1.1 1.1 1.1 ...
  ..$ CopyNumber : int [1:309579] 2 7 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

Comment: but when I run df <- read.delim(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
df2 <- read.delim(file.choose(),header=TRUE) total <- merge(df, df2, c("Chromosome","Start")) it seems to merge OK so I dont think its a typo problem.

Comment: I had to restart R studio and now I'm back to the object 'files' not found error. Is there perhaps a way of specifying a PATH to a folder and then iterating through pairs of files sorted alphabetically or something?

Comment: Hi. Yes they are in the getwd and I've tried it in the console and I get the same error message. I have then just tried running the code lstN <- lapply(split(files, gsub("[A-Za-z]\\..*", "", files)),
               function(.files) {
                 total <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., c("Chromosome","Start")), 
                                 lapply(.files, function(x) read.table(x, header=TRUE, sep='')))
                 View(total)
               }) but I get the same error message again

Comment: If `read.delim` is only working, then can you try `d1 <- read.delim(paste(getwd(), 'File_1a.txt', sep="/"), header=TRUE)` with the appropriate `sep`.  If that works, we can use that for the `lapply`

Comment: That seems to work but where do I put it in the body of the code?

Comment: So depressing. I still get the error Error in split(files, gsub("[A-Za-z]\\..*", "", files)) : 
  object 'files' not found.. I have rechecked the working directory which is where the files are and this is fine. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: even just running files[1:4] gives me the same error in both studio and console. Must be something fundamental

Comment: If you can share subset of two pairs of datasets in dropbox or something, I can check whether it works with the code.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9l3m46ugjrswkne/File_1b.txt?dl=0           https://www.dropbox.com/s/js70ayd0nf9q92h/File_1a.txt?dl=0

Comment: But, this is just one pair of dataset,right? which I think would work with your `file.choose()`

Comment: I was able to run it without any problems using the `first` code itself.  ie.  `sapply(lstN, nrow)# File_1  File_2 
5580601       2`  Here, the `File_2` is based on the example `File_2a`, `File_2b` I created.  The print result is `[1] 90.90519
[1] 9.094809
[1] 100
[1] 0`

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for me then. Shame

Comment: Can you tell some details about the R/Rstudio versions and whether you are using linux/windows etc?

Comment: I am using Rstudio 0.98.994 and Mac OSX 10.9.2. The R console is 3.1.0 GUI 1.64 Snow Leopard build (6734).

Comment: Is it possible for you to check this on non-Mac systems?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the operation in the `same` columns in each `pair` of files i.e. (`File_1a` and `File_1b`, `File_2a` and `File_2b` etc), you could do (I am just copy/pasting your code as you mentioned that it works well. These steps could have been simplified if you had showed few lines of your dataset.)

```
lstN <- lapply(split(files, gsub("[A-Za-z]\\..*", "", files)),
            function(.files) {
            total <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='Start'), 
                      lapply(.files, function(x) read.table(x, header=TRUE)))
            total[,5][total[,5]=='2'] <- 'd'
            total[,9][total[,9]=='2'] <- 'd'
            total[,5][total[,5] < 2 & total[,5] !="d"] <- "l"
            total[,9][total[,9] < 2 & total[,9] !="d"] <- "l"
            total[,5][total[,5] > 2 & total[,5] !="l" & total[,5] !="d"] <- "g"
            total[,9][total[,9] > 2 & total[,9] !="l" & total[,9] !="d"] <- "g"
            total$agree <- ifelse((total[,5] == total[,9]),"agree","disagree")
            print(sum(total$agree == "agree")/nrow(total)*100)
            print(sum(total$agree == "disagree")/nrow(total)*100)
            total 
                })
```

#### Update

Using the similar `format` of `data` in the updated post along with the `uploaded` dataset gives

```
  lapply(lstN, head,2)
  #  $File_1
  #  Start Chromosome.x Ratio.x MedianRatio.x CopyNumber.x Chromosome.y   Ratio.y
  #1     1            1      -1            -1            d            1  0.697902
  #2     1            1      -1            -1            d            X -1.000000
  #  MedianRatio.y CopyNumber.y    agree
  #1        1.2794            g disagree
  #2       -1.0000            d    agree

  #$File_2
  #  Start Chromosome.x rt.x med.x CN.x Chromosome.y rt.y med.y CN.y agree
  #1     1           10    1     3    d            5    2    13    d agree
  #2     1           10    1     3    d           10    1     3    d agree
```

#### Update2

Using `getwd()` to specify the `path` and `read.delim`

```
 lstN <- lapply(split(files, gsub("[A-Za-z]\\..*", "", files)),
        function(.files) {
        total <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='Start'), 
                  lapply(.files, function(x) read.delim(paste(getwd(),
                     x, sep="/"), header=TRUE, sep='')))
        total[,5][total[,5]=='2'] <- 'd'
        total[,9][total[,9]=='2'] <- 'd'
        total[,5][total[,5] < 2 & total[,5] !="d"] <- "l"
        total[,9][total[,9] < 2 & total[,9] !="d"] <- "l"
        total[,5][total[,5] > 2 & total[,5] !="l" & total[,5] !="d"] <- "g"
        total[,9][total[,9] > 2 & total[,9] !="l" & total[,9] !="d"] <- "g"
        total$agree <- ifelse((total[,5] == total[,9]),"agree","disagree")
        print(sum(total$agree == "agree")/nrow(total)*100)
        print(sum(total$agree == "disagree")/nrow(total)*100)
        total 
            })
```

#### data

I created 4 files ie. `File_1a.txt`, `File_1b.txt`, `File_2a.txt`, and `File_2b.txt` in the `working directory`.

```
 set.seed(29) #creating some sample data in a `list`
 lst <- lapply(1:4, function(i) cbind(Start=sample(1:9, 5, replace=FALSE),
          as.data.frame(matrix(sample(-5:10, 5*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=4)) ) )

 nm1 <- paste0('File_', paste0(rep(1:2, each=2), c('a', 'b')), '.txt')
 #create the files using `write.table`
 invisible(lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) 
     write.table(lst[[i]], file=nm1[i], quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)))

 rm(list=ls())
 ls()
 #character(0)
 files <- list.files(pattern='File_\\d+[A-Za-z]')
 files #files created in the working directory
 #[1] "File_1a.txt" "File_1b.txt" "File_2a.txt" "File_2b.txt"
```

Comment: Perhaps Im being a bit dumb... I put my files called File_1 and File_2 etc in the working directory. When I use the above code I get the error: Error in split(files, gsub("[A-Za-z]\\..*", "", files)) : object 'files' not found

Comment: It is [1] "File_1.txt" "File_2.txt" "File_2"     "File_2"     "File_3"     "File_3"     "File_4"     "File_4" and they are all .txt

Comment: @user3632206  Based on the info you gave, I get `gsub("[A-Za-z]\\..*", "", files)#[1] "File_1" "File_1" "File_2" "File_2"`

Comment: So the files are called File_1a File_1b etc but the gsub routine gives me "File_1" "File_2" "File_2"

Comment: @user3632206  Yes, that is the expected result. Just do, `split(files, gsub("[A-Za-z]\\..*", "", files))` and check what you get

Comment: OK. I get $File_2 [1] "File_2a.txt" "File_2b.txt" so that seems to work OK. In that case I don't know what the problem was. Seems to be working OK now. On another note, I don't seem to be getting a successful merge as I now get an error which says Error in `[.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 9) : undefined columns selected and when I do View(total) it looks as though the file isnt merged

Comment: @user3632206  I would suspect that the `column names` in some of the dataset especially the `Start` may have some leading or lagging space or perhaps be different.

Comment: but it works fine when I do df <- read.delim(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
df2 <- read.delim(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
total <- merge(df, df2, c("X.Chromosome","Start"))

Comment: @user3632206  Please check the `str` of the list created i.e. `str(lapply(split(files, gsub("[A-Za-z]\\..*", "", files)), function(.files) {lapply(.files, function(x) read.table(x, header=TRUE))})[[1]])`  I would suspect it to be case of `delimiter` issue.  You may have to use the `sep=''` or `sep='\t'` within the `read.table`